# PayPal IPN always return INVALID on requests

Tags: php, joomla, paypal, paypal-ipn

Trying to setup the PayPal IPN to verify payments on my website, but every single request I've tried returns `INVALID`. I can't figure out what the problem is and where it might be screwing up. I was thinking the problem might have been Joomla! adding the `page`, `view` and `task` variables, so I tried removing them from the `$_POST`, but the request returned `INVALID` all the same.

Here's a list of all of the `$_POST` data PayPal is sending me and I am returning to verify validity:

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 3.40
    [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [payer_id] => F57P3MMS6UKNC
    [tax] => 0.00
    [address_street] => 1275, Chemin du Tremblay
Suite 201
    [payment_date] => 06:51:30 Jul 28, 2014 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => UTF-8
    [address_zip] => j4n 0g2
    [first_name] => Michael
    [mc_fee] => 0.40
    [address_country_code] => CA
    [address_name] => Michael Bourdeau
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => gdwppsend@outlook.com
    [address_country] => Canada
    [address_city] => Longueuil
    [quantity] => 1
    [payer_email] => gdwpppay@outlook.com
    [verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AOvJSJy.aGpnmllVEvU2.7EGndXL
    [txn_id] => 5RW992040P712271B
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => Bourdeau
    [address_state] => Quebec
    [receiver_email] => gdwppsend@outlook.com
    [payment_fee] => 
    [receiver_id] => BKHMT27W3EMDE
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] => GÃ©ant du web - Facture #3884
    [mc_currency] => CAD
    [item_number] => 3884
    [residence_country] => CA
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [payment_gross] => 
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [merchant_return_link] => click here
    [auth] => AGtLwVTUzpbI8nw16O3Cv11hNv6uRom2.oebD1GgLQuWzNp7OqVXz-nY-qzw2QunZsrVzDZqDuwxvYR0vEmvkQg
    [view] => paypalipn
    [task] => run
)
```

A copy of the PHP code sending the request:

```
$postdata = $_POST;

//Get config file
$cfgFile = GDWCOMP_ADMINROOT.'includes'.DS.'cpanel.config.gdw.php';
if ( file_exists($cfgFile) ) {
    include($cfgFile);
} else {
    $gdwconf = array();
}

//Live or sandbox PayPal
if ($gdwconf['ppsandbox'] == 1) {
    $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
} else {
    $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
}

$postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (count($postdata) > 0) {
    foreach($postdata as $key => $val) {
        $postFields .= '&'.$key.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($val));
    }
}

//Validate info sent with paypal
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_POST            => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $postFields
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$curlerror = curl_error($ch);
if ($curlerror) {
    die('CURL-ERROR: '.$curlerror);
}

echo $result;
echo $postFields;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';

//Log results
$file = ($result) ? 'pp_results_veri.txt' : 'pp_results_unveri.txt';
if (count($postdata) > 0) {
    $this->writeLog($file, ": (".$result.") : ".json_encode($postdata));
} else {
    $this->writeLog($file, ": (".$result.") "); //Write to log.
}

exit;
```

Comment: Is this the correct item name?
[item_name] => GÃ©ant du web - Facture #3884

Comment: @randstraw Special characters are being passed as such, but do appear appropriately on the website and paypal. Either way, it's not the issue as I've tested the transaction without it.